# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, mysql, insert

No puedo ingresar datos a mi bd por este error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
> number: parameter was not defined in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\G6-Proyecto\crudclientes.php:21 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\G6-Proyecto\crudclientes.php(21):
> PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\G6-Proyecto\crudclientes.php on line 21

```
    <?php include("template/cabecera-crud.php")?>

<?php 
$txtid=(isset($_POST['txtid']))?$_POST['txtid']:"";
$txtnombres=(isset($_POST['txtnombres']))?$_POST['txtnombres']:"";
$txtapellidos=(isset($_POST['txtapellidos']))?$_POST['txtapellidos']:"";
$txtcorreo=(isset($_POST['txtcorreo']))?$_POST['txtcorreo']:"";
$txtpass=(isset($_POST['txtpass']))?$_POST['txtpass']:"";
$accion=(isset($_POST['accion']))?$_POST['accion']:"";

include("config/bd.php");

switch($accion){
    case "Agregar":
        $sentenciaSQL=$conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO clientes (id, nombres, apellidos, correo, contraseña) VALUES (:id, :nombres, :apellidos, :correo, :contraseña);");
        $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(':id',$txtid);
        $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(':nombres',$txtnombres);
        $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(':apellidos',$txtapellidos);
        $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(':correo',$txtcorreo);
        $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(':contraseña',$txtpass);
        $sentenciaSQL->execute();

        echo "Presionando el boton Agregar";
        break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en estas 2 líneas:

```php
// ...
$sentenciaSQL = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO clientes (id, nombres, apellidos, correo, contraseña) VALUES (:id, :nombres, :apellidos, :correo, :contraseña);");
// ...
$sentenciaSQL->bindParam(':contraseña',$txtpass);
// ...
```

Se arregla cambiando `:contraseña` por otra palabra que no contenga `ñ`, ni otros símbolos ilegales.

[Caracteres permitidos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5810058/1545868) para los *placeholder* de enlace: `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z` y `_`